# Unique $k$ tuples from a population of $n$ types

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

(The inspiration of the problem is [here](https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Invoker).)

> Suppose there are $n$ types of, say, marbles $1,\ldots,n$. How many unique $k$-tuples are there? For convenience, let $S(n,k)$ be the answer.

Ordering within a tuple doesn't matter. For example, with $k=3$ and $n=3$, we have $S(3,3)=10$:
$$
(1,1,1)\\
(1,1,2),\quad(1,1,3),\\
(1,2,2),\quad(1,2,3),\quad(1,3,3),\\
(2,2,2),\quad(2,2,3),\quad(2,3,3),\quad(3,3,3).
$$
(Here, $(1,1,2)$, for example, denotes a tuple consisting of two marbles of type 1 and one marble of type 2.)

Maybe we can do induction on $k$ for any fixed $n$?

Comment: I'm not sure this is clear.  What does $(1,1,1)$ mean, in the case $(k,n)=(3,3)$?  Does that mean I choose one of each type of marble?  Why then can't I have the triple $(4,4,4)$ if I choose four of each type?  Is there an implied cap of some sort?  Or does $(1,1,1)$ mean that I choose type $1$ three times?

Comment: @lulu $(1,1,1)$ means all three marbles are of type 1. I'll add this clarification to the main text.

Comment: Ok, so then $S(2,3)=4$ since we could have $(1,1,1), (1,1,2), (1,2,2), (2,2,2)$?

Comment: @lulu Yeah, that looks right to me.

Comment: Isn't this just the number of ways to put $k$ indistinguishable balls into $n$ buckets, so ${n+k-1\choose n-1}$ or ${5\choose2}=10$ in the example?

Comment: @saulspatz Combinatorics is a weak point but that sounds promising. Perhaps you can turn it into an answer?

Comment: Each of your $k-$tuples is uniquely specified by counting the number of $1's$, $2's$, $3's$ etc.  Thus this is a [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem.  Note:  this is the same approach as recommended by @saulspatz

Comment: @lulu I see, so $k$ stars, $n$ bars, and allowing the possibility of no stars between the bars? It's unfortunate that my $n$ and $k$ notation is a flip with the $n$ and $k$ notation in the Stars and Bars wiki article.

Comment: For some reason that happens all the time (that the letters get reversed).  I suppose that's an illusion...I mean, I recall all the times the notation confuses me and forget the times when it just works.  But it really seems to happen all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars) problem.  We can express it as the number of ways to place $k$ indistinguishable balls in $n$ buckets.  For example, if $n=4$ and $k=3$ then putting $2$ ball ins bucket $1$ and 1 in bucket $4$ corresponds to the tuple $(1,1,4).$

The number of ways to do this is well-known to be $${n+k-1\choose n-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

It's not a closed form expression or a generalization but an idea:

When we have $k$-tuples, let us find the partitions of $k$. For example, for $k = 3$, we have

- $3$
- $2+1$
- $1+1+1$

Now let each number in summation represent the "# of repeated marbles". For example we include $(1,1,1)$ to the partition $3$ while $(1,1,2)$ and $(1,2,2)$ should be included to $2+1$. Then for $n = 3$, $k = 3$ case, we have in total

$$\binom{3}{1}+\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}+\binom{3}{3} = 10$$

tuples where $\binom{3}{1}$ is the number of ways of choosing the elements of partition $3$, $\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}$ is number of ways of choosing the two times repeated element (for example, for $(1,1,2)$ it is $1$) and one non-repeated element (it is $2$ in the same example) of partition $2+1$ and $\binom{3}{3}$ is number of ways of choosing $3$ different elements of partition $1+1+1$.